# Reference for option pricing, binomial multi-period model using martingales and conditional expectations

Tags: option-pricing, reference-request, binomial-tree

The title basically says it all. I am looking for a reference text on the pricing of options in a binomial multi-period model. It should be mathemathically rigorous using martingales and conditional expectations yet be self-contained as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your hands on a physical copy of by [Stochastic Calculus for Finance I: The Binomial Asset Pricing Model (Springer Finance)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387249680) by S. Shreve, I strongly encourage it.

If you can't, here is an [electronic document](http://efinance.org.cn/cn/FEshuo/stochastic.pdf) which adresses exactly the same issues in the first chapters (and a little bit more in the following).